# Is there any solution about re-parenting on A-Frame without cloneNode()?

Tags: aframe

On A-Frame scene, I want change entity's(a-box) parent.

So I doing removeChild() and appendChild().

But this work did not work as my intended.

It seemed that Object3D was lost when removeChild() was done. (box disappeared!)

Is there a way to change parent without cloneNode()?

**I want to move the original box, not the box's clone.**

A-Frame version is 0.9.1

```
<a-scene>
   <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -1" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
   <a-box position="-1 0.5 1" rotation="0 45 0" width="1" height="1" depth="1" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
   <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 1" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
   <a-plane rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>

   <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
   <a-entity position="0 0 3.8">
     <a-camera></a-camera>
   </a-entity>
</a-scene>

<script>
   // this code doesn't work as my intended
   var plane = document.querySelector('a-plane');
   var box = document.querySelector('a-box');
   box.parentEl.removeChild(box);
   plane.appendChild(box);

   // is this the only way?
   // var plane = document.querySelector('a-plane');
   // var box = document.querySelector('a-box');
   // var copyBox = box.cloneNode(true);
   // box.parentEl.removeChild(box);
   // plane.appendChild(copyBox);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We hope that moving the DOM node works, but it's not fully tested. Might just be an issue. You can also just move the three.js object3D which is a lot faster.

```
const obj = el.object3D;
anotherEl.object3D.add(obj);
```